# Should I chew/munch food while eating with closed mouth or open?

Tags: food, sound

I used to eat with moderately opened mouth. Some people suggested me that its make noise while eating and to eat with closed mouth always, but I am feeling difficulty while following their suggestion. Is it okay to close and open mouth while eating or else how to do it?

Comment: Some don't care, some do. Chomping sounds go right through me, which generally happen from eating with mouth open. Besides, who wants to see all that food being churned around? No reason for the mouth to be open IMO.

Comment: Do you feel less difficulty if you put less food in your mouth at once? What happens if you take smaller bites?

Comment: I did not try till now. @Stan I hope its nice idea.....